# RecyclerView: how to add OnClick() after onLongClick()

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Recyclerview display list of mp3 files, when I click on any file the music of clicked file is start playing and when I long click on any file I change the action bar to another action bar until here everything is fine, but when I try to click the files again after entering action mode I click the files and music still playing

MyAdapter.java:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private EditText mEditText;
    public boolean is_in_action_mode = false;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    private onItemClickListener mListener;
    private  onItemLongClickListener mLongListener;


    public MyAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RecyclerItem> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public interface onItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
        void onMenuClick(int position, View view);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public  interface onItemLongClickListener{
        boolean onItemLongClick(int position);
    }


    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(onItemLongClickListener longClickListener){
        mLongListener = longClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view, mListener, mLongListener);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final RecyclerItem currentItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.txtTitel.setText(currentItem.getTitle());

        if (!is_in_action_mode){

            is_in_action_mode = false;

        } else {

            is_in_action_mode = true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView txtTitel;
        public TextView txtOptionDigit;
        LinearLayout linearLayout ;
        CardView cardView;
        FrameLayout frameLayout;
        MainActivity mainActivity;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, onItemClickListener listener, onItemLongClickListener longListener) {
            super(itemView);

            txtTitel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);
            frameLayout = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
            frameLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

            txtTitel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){ 
                            listener.onItemClick(position);  
                        }                    
                    }
                }
            });

            txtTitel.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if (longListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){ 
                            longListener.onItemLongClick(position);  
                        }                 
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){ 
                            listener.onMenuClick(position, view); 
                        }                  
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //when a user select or unselect a cardview this method will invoked
            mainActivity.prepareSelection(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public void upateAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> selection_list) {
        for (RecyclerItem recyclerItem : selection_list){
            listItems.remove(recyclerItem);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView; //this variable will contain the recyclerview that I created on layout

    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> mListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private EditText mEditText;

    ActionMode mActionMode;

    int mCurrentPosition;

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    boolean is_in_action_mode = false; 

    TextView counter_text_view;

    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> selection_list = new ArrayList<>();

    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        //to hide the textview counter on
        counter_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCounter);
        counter_text_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        createDataSet();
        buildRecyclerView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void createDataSet() {
        File path = getExternalFilesDir("MyFolder");

        File file[] = path.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            mListItems.add(new RecyclerItem(file[i].getName()));
        }
    }

    private void buildRecyclerView() {

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        //Set adapter
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, mListItems);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                playMusic(position);
                mCurrentPosition = position;

            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuClick(int position, View view) {
                menuClicked(position, view);
            }


        });

        mAdapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new MyAdapter.onItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(int position) {
                mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(null);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
                mToolbar.getMenu().clear();
                mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_action_mode);
                counter_text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                is_in_action_mode = true;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //to display a back button on the contextual action bar
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void playMusic(int position) {

        String path = String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir("MyFolder"));

        try{
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + "/" + mListItems.get(position).getTitle());
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }catch (IOException e){
            //Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),e.getMessage() );
        }
    }



    public void prepareSelection(View view, int position){

        //this method will invoked when the user select or unselect cardview
        if (((FrameLayout) view).isSelected()){
            //is_in_action_mode = true;
            selection_list.add(mListItems.get(position));
            view.setBackgroundColor(0XFF6200EE);
            counter = counter + 1;
            updateCounter(counter);
        } else { //if the user didn't select the cardview we have to remove that item from selection list
            selection_list.remove(mListItems.get(position));
            counter = counter - 1;
            updateCounter(counter);
        }

    }

    public void updateCounter(int counter){
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter_text_view.setText("0 item selected");
        } else {
            counter_text_view.setText(counter + " item selected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_delete){

            //remove the selected item from the adapter
            MyAdapter myAdapter = (MyAdapter) mAdapter;
            myAdapter.upateAdapter(selection_list);

            clearActionMode();
        }

        //now handle the home or back button
        else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            clearActionMode();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clearActionMode(){
        is_in_action_mode = false;

        //clear the menu in the toolbar
        mToolbar.getMenu().clear();
        mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_activity_main);

        //remove the back button from the toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        //hide the text view (counter) from the toolbar
        counter_text_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //update the text in the counter
        counter_text_view.setText("0 item selected");

        counter = 0;
        selection_list.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (is_in_action_mode){
            clearActionMode();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put an if condition in your onClick listner like:

```
if(actionMode == false){

    //Open music file

 }else{

   //Select music file (show some indicator for the selected music file like a tick or something)

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need when I start selecting files from the list, I need to change the backgroung of the selected files to any color, for example (Blue), the counter of the selected files is not counting at all, it look like I'm still on normal mode not action mode

Comment: you can take help from youtube videos on this topic. I did too and implemented the same functionality in my app .

Comment: but all of them are using checkbox for selecting files in recyclerview